# Hide list column name

Tags: list, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I am using Insert Data View function from SharePoint Designer 2007 to insert a list created in parent site to a child site. Now the list displays correctly.

My question is, how to hide the column name (displayed at the top of list content rows) in my child site (I want to show the list rows only, no need to show the list column name)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using a Data View you have the ability to modify the underlying XSLT.  Go to the web part's properties and grab the source.  Edit it in notepad or more friendly like VS.NET.

In this case, you just want to remove the TH row.

Comment: "have the ability to modify the underlying XSLT" -- can you show me how to modify XSLT?

Comment: From the browser, Edit the page, go to the web part and select "Modify Shared Web Part" then click the "XSL Editor" button at the top of the property page.  This launches a pop-up with the XSL code that renders the output.  It can be edited in place, but the formatting makes modifications difficult so I normally copy it into a different editor.

Also, you have the option of linking to an XSL file somewhere else.  A lot of times it is better to do that since you can maintain and version the file in a document library.

Answer (score 2):

I find that I can simply click oh the cell you are talking about and delete right from design mode.  Otherwise as next_connect indicates the xslt can be modified directly.  Probably the best way to go.